# Measure current and voltage with same ADC input without switch

Tags: current, adc, industrial

I am looking to design a device that measures signals from industrial transmitters with values of ±20mA and ±10V.
I want to use the ADS8674 from TI as the ADC but i want to use the same inputs to measure both voltages and current using different connectors, just like Allen bradley AI modules.

[image: Analog input module from Allen Bradley]

[image]

I have made a Diagram using a diode to block the input voltage from flowing through the resistor and this resistor would be used to sense the input current. Either a voltage source or current source would be connected at once.

[image]

Do you think this is a better solution than using a resistor divider network, and would this work to measure current with both polarities (+20mA and -20mA)?

Answer (score 1):

That circuit won't measure both polarities of current, when the current is negative the voltage across the resistor will be blocked by the diode.

Are you limited to a certain number of connector contacts? If not you could have a set of contacts that connects the resistor into the circuit when the current load is connected. That way you could eliminate the diode.
[image]

Comment: There is no problem with the number of the contact, but the way i understand this is that you would need to bridge the contacts manually?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Yes. I'm basing this on the current and voltage  sources have separate cables with connectors that plug into the ADC unit and only one is connected to the ADC at a time. You would use 3 pin connectors wired as shown, in the connector for current you connect pins 1 & 2 so when it's plugged in the resistor is connected. If that's not the way you're connecting them let me know and I'll see if there's some other way to do it.

Comment: that would work but i would like to eliminate they manual bridging i'm orden to connect they resistor.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I don't understand what you want to do then. You'll need to add details of exactly how you are planning to connect this.

Comment: you are right i would be using different cables for current and voltage and different connectors for each. But in the first diagram in your image it looks like you are connecting pin 1 with 2 manually. am i right?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Yes, when you put the connectors on the cable you just add a little jumper between those pins.

Comment: Yeah thats one of they thigs i wanted to avoid. Manually put a jumper

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Can you tell me exactly why you want to avoid that? If you're having cables made adding a jumper should be trivial. I think your alternative is going to be to put a resistor in each current probe, or design a circuit to detect which kind of probe is used and switch the input configuration accordingly.